# how to avoid group by on a lot of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two large tables

-Master table A: 1.4million rows
-Detail table B: 9 million rows

B has a foreign key to A.

Basically I need all the 25 detail-fields from table A + in this case a count on B.

Now I have the following pseudo query:

```
Select
       A.field1,
       A.field2,
       ...
       A.field25,
       Count(b.id)
 from
       A left outer join B on B.fkAid = A.id
 Group by 
       A.id,
       A.field1,
       A.field2,
       ...
       A.field25
Order by A.field1
```

The Query plans show the grouping by to take a lot of time (no surprise).

Is there a more efficient way to do this kind of Select?

Comment: Clustered index on B (fkAid, B.id) and PK on A

Comment: Does the `GROUP BY` list include the PK on A? Not clear in your question. If so adding additional table A columns to the group by might be tedious but shouldn't affect the query plan.

Comment: Sorry, yes it does. Actually I need all the details of A so grouping on the PK would be enough. updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using a common table expression (you tagged it SQL Server 2008?)

```
WITH CountB AS
(
    SELECT A.aId, value= Count(*)
    FROM A left outer join B on B.fkAid = A.id
    GROUP BY A.id
)
Select
   A.field1,
   A.field2,
   ...
   A.field25,
   CountB.value
from
   A left outer join CountB on A.id = CountB.aId
Order by A.field1
```

Comment: Seems more than 50% faster. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Pleun - Be interesting to know why. Every experiment I've done so far has had this version come out with greater cost.

Answer (score 4):

You might try with a correlated subquery - but it may be even less efficient:

```
Select
       A.field1,
       A.field2,
       ...
       A.field25,
       (select Count(*) from B where B.fkAid = A.id)
 from
       A
Order by A.field1
```

I'd actually expect the left join and grouping to be more efficient if there's no WHERE clause, unless the columns in table A are very wide.

One other possibility would be:

```
Select
       A.field1,
       A.field2,
       ...
       A.field25,
       Coalesce(b.Cnt,0)
 from
       A left join
       (select fkAid,COUNT(*) from B group by fkAId) b (ID,Cnt)
       on A.ID = b.ID
Order by A.field1
```

Which might be best with no where clauses involved.

Comment: "but it may be even less efficient:
" - not sure how that is useful!

Comment: @Mitch - it's one of those things where you have to try each combination and see which works best given your actual data - I'm not an absolutist who says things like "never do X" - I like to give people options. The OP has indicated that they're already able to examine plans.

Comment: Stabbing in the dark is sometimes effective; I prefer concrete approaches.

Comment: @Mitch - without having his data, knowing how close the pseudo-query is to the real query, and being able to run the queries, I've no means to assess how efficient each approach will be. However, in my experience, *usually* the left join and group will be more efficient. So I was trying to set an expectation - if they try it and it's less efficient, so be it.

Comment: It seems it *must* be slower... you are doing a select for every row -- has to be slower in the first query

Comment: @Hogan - I've seen queries speed up by switching in both directions. But it's probably 80% speed up by switching to left join, and 20% speed up by switching to correlation.

Comment: It would have to internally optimize it to a join then -- 1.4 million selects would "not be so fast."

Comment: @Hogan I will try just to see... This one is running now - your solution is the next one I will give a try

Comment: For what it's worth, SQL Server is actually very good about optimizing subqueries. Some other RDBMSs aren't so good and would actually spawn a SELECT subquery for each and every correlated row. The SQL Server optimizer avoids this folly. I don't have a specific performance metric but it would not end with doom and gloom.

Comment: +1 Thanks - this was slightly faster but the common table expression performed better.

Comment: @Paul - I have seen doom and gloom with SQL Server... I think it depends on availability of indexes data types etc...

Comment: @Hogan: That should go w/o saying. If you don't index your tables properly it won't matter how you query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `OUTER APPLY`:

```
Select
       A.field1,
       A.field2,
       ...
       A.field25,
       C.Quant
 from
       A OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) Quant FROM B WHERE A.id = B.fkAid) AS C
Order by A.field1
```